# Can meteor:cluster serve several application / act as a reverse proxy?

Tags: meteor, cluster-computing, reverse-proxy

I am trying to understand how does meteorhacks:cluster work for serving several websites. On their [official page](https://meteorhacks.com/cluster-a-different-kind-of-load-balancer-for-meteor.html) they wrote:

*Normally, if we need to scale a Meteor app, we need to put it behind a load balancer like Nginx or HaProxy*

That is right, however HaProxy (or Nginx) is not only used as a load balancer but mainly as a **reverse proxy**. For example my server has 3 different meteor app running, each one on their own port. When a client connects to the port 80, My reverse proxy watch the url and route it to the right meteor app instance:

I deploy and run 3 meteor apps on the server (using MeteorUp for example)

```
localhost:3000
localhost:3001
localhost:3002
```

I then configure my proxy with a routing table like the one below

```
app1.com:80 -> localhost:3000
app2.com:80 -> localhost:3001
app3.com:80 -> localhost:3002
```

And everything works fine this way. Now making use of meteor:cloud is it able to do this job of:

1. Associate an url to a service (app1.com, app2.com,…)
2. Route the client to the corresponding meteor service ?

Comment: If you post an issue on the github repo you should get a quick response from the meteorhacks team

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock sure and they are reactive, but it's neither an issue nor a feature request. Just a question regarding the use of meteor:cluster. Perhaps this feature it is just out of the meteor:cluster scope (or not… I just do not get it right now)

Comment: Yeah. I get that. In a way it is an issue because you have a problem with the documentation. But either way if you post an issue you'll get a response